# Show that the following sequence converges $x_n=1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\dots+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} - 2\sqrt{n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

Given 
$$x_n=1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\dots+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} - 2\sqrt{n}$$
I thought to use the weiestrass theorem, I found out $x_{n+1}<x_{n}$  this means that the sequence is monotonous, but as I look it tends to $-1$?

Comment: Do you know, for a start, how to prove it converges? (comparison with integral, or Riemann sums)

Comment: yes, but not sure in this case

Comment: $x_1=-1$ and $x_{n+1}<x_n$ implies, that $x_n$ cannot converge to $-1$.

Comment: "I found out xn+1<xn"  If so then if you can also prove they are bounded below that will be enough to prove they converge.  You don't have to find *what* they converge to...."but as I look it tends to −1?"  Why "but"? Isn't that what you want?  If you can show $-1$ is a lower bound you'd be down. That wouldn't mean that $-1$ is the *greatest* lower bound but it means it does converg.  (Caveat: This comment is made with *no* calculations or work; it is based *entirely* on statements made in the OP)

Comment: @fleablood No, $-1$ is a upper bound, not a lower bound!

Comment: "but as I look it tends to −1" why do you say that?  $x_1 = -1$ and $x_2 = 1+\frac 1{\sqrt 2} - 2\sqrt 2=\frac {\sqrt 2+1-4}{\sqrt 2}=1-\frac {3}{\sqrt 2} < -1$ and as you said $x_n$ is decreasing....

Comment: @Fakemistake  I *SAID*  "(Caveat: This comment is made with no calculations or work; it is based entirely on statements made in the OP)".  Still holds.  Most show it is bounded below.  But if $-1$ is an upper bound that doesn't help us in the least.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that$$x_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}-\int_0^n\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}}=-\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\color{blue}{\int_{k-1}^k\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}}\right).$$The blue expression is non-negative, but for $k\ge2$ is at most $\frac{1}{\sqrt{k-1}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}$, so we can bound $x_n$ with a convergent telescoping series.

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{align}x_{n+1}-x_n&=-2\sqrt{n+1}+\frac1{\sqrt{n+1}}+2\sqrt n\\
&=\frac{2\sqrt n\sqrt{n+1}-(2n+1)}{\sqrt{n+1}}=\frac{-1}{\sqrt{n+1}\left(2\sqrt n\sqrt{n+1}+2n+1\right)}\end{align}$$
So we can see that
$$0\ge x_{n+1}-x_n\ge\frac{-1}{4n^{3/2}}$$
So
$$0\ge x_{N+1}-x_1=x_{N+1}+1\ge\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{-1}{4n^{3/2}}$$
Since the latter sum converges by the integral test it follows that ${x_n}$ is a monotonically decreasing sequence with a lower bound so it converges to a limit.

Comment: @Fakemistake You seem to be forgetting about the $$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{\sqrt k}$$ part of $x_n$.

Comment: Of course the first line is correct.  $x_{n+1} = (1+....+\frac 1{\sqrt{n}})+\frac 1{\sqrt{n+1}} - 2\sqrt{n+1}$ and $x_n =  (1+....+\frac 1{\sqrt{n}})- 2\sqrt{n}$ so $x_{n+1}-x_n = \frac 1{\sqrt{n+1}} -2\sqrt{n+1} + 2\sqrt{n}$.

Comment: @user5713492 No it was the $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}$ part, so I deleted my first comment.

Answer (score 1):

Note that for $k\geq 1$:
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt k}>2\left(\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt{k}\right)=\int_k^{k+1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\,dx $$
(You can also verify this inequality directly by squaring both sides.) Then apply this for $k=1,2,\ldots,n$ to arrive at
$$\begin{align}
1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\cdots+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}&>2\left(\sqrt 2-\sqrt1\right)+2\left(\sqrt 3-\sqrt 2\right)+\cdots+2\left(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt n\right)\\ &=2\left(\sqrt{n+1}-1\right)
\end{align}$$
Hence,
$$x_n>2\left(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}-1\right)>2(0-1)=-2$$
This tells you $x_n$ is bounded below. Combine this with the fact $x_n$ is a decreasing sequence to conclude it converges.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose m $\in \mathbb{Z} $ $(m \succ 0 )$ is a constant.

Let $x_{n+m}=1+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\cdots+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n+m}}-2\sqrt{n+m}$

then $x_{n+m}-x_{n}= \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}+\cdots +\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n+m}}+2\sqrt{n}-2\sqrt{n+m}= \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}+\cdots +\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n+m}}-\dfrac{2m}{\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n+m}}$

Consider$ \dfrac{m}{\sqrt{n+m}}-\dfrac{2m}{\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n+m}} \prec x_{n+m}-x_n \prec                                                \dfrac{m}{\sqrt{n+1}}-\dfrac{2m}{\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n+m}}$

$\lim(x_{n+m}-x_{n})$ when $n\to +\infty$,so $\lim(x_{n+m}-x_{n})=0$

In fact ,you can prove that it is a cauchy sequence.(when $m \succ 0$)

Consider $|x_{n+m}-x_{n}|\leq \dfrac{m}{\sqrt{n+1}}$

when $n \to +\infty $,$ \lim|x_{n+m}-x_n|=0 $