# Show that the following sequence converges $ x_n = \arctan 1 + \dots +\arctan \frac{1}{n} - \ln \sqrt{n^2+1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Show that the following sequence converges $ x_n = \arctan 1 + \dots +\arctan \frac{1}{n} - \ln \sqrt{n^2+1}$ so I can rewrite using series $ \sum_{k=1}^{n} \arctan \frac{1}{k} - \ln \sqrt{n^2+1}$

Comment: That's the second of two very similar questions. Are you writing your homework here? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3585583/show-that-the-following-sequence-converges-x-n-1-frac1-sqrt2-dots-frac

Comment: is that n in the natural log supposed to be a k?

Comment: Have you tried the ratio test?

Comment: Point is, is there any effort in an attempt to solve the problem.....

Comment: so I tried to see if the string is decreasing or rising but I came to a relationship in the arctan and logarithm so I can't compare them

Comment: Hint :
 $$x_n=\sum_{k=1}^n (\arctan(\frac{1}{k})-\frac{1}{k})+(\sum_{1}^n \frac{1}{k}-\log n)+(\log n-\log(\sqrt{n^2+1}))$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is
$x-x^3/3 < \arctan(x) < x
$,
$\lim_{n \to \infty} (\ln(n)-\sum_{k=1}^n 1/k)
$
exists,
and
$n < \sqrt{n^2+1}
\lt n+1/(2n)
$.

Your turn.